# How do I export a CSV from Access?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, csv

I am trying to import an access database to mysql. I have created a mysql database, but do not want to use all of the colums in the access database. Is there a way to export only certain colums from the access database to csv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Make a query on the table with only the columns you want, and save it.
2) Select the query, and then got to File->Export (Select Save As "text *.txt, *cvs, etc.") and follow the prompts